# Python Kivy Black Screen - tutorial taken from youtube

Tags: python, kivy

I follow tutorial on youtube. But my outcome is black screen. I did change some small things but I don't know where is my mistake.
I use pycharm and it do not show errors or mistake.

My .py file code is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget



Builder.load_file('awesome.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
        self.ids.click_label.text = value

class AwesomeApp(App):
    def builder(self):

        return MyLayout()


if __name__== "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

My .kv file name is awesome.kv

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            id: click_label
            text: "Wybierz opcje"
            font_size: 32
        Spinner:
            id: spinner_id
            text: "Ulubiona pizza"
            value: ['peperoni','mushrooms', 'cheese']

            on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)
```

Where I made mistake?
Is there anyway to see where I do mistake in pycharm in the future?

Pycharm do not show indent errors in kv files - why?

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled AwesomeApp class method:

```
def builder(self):
```

it should be:

```
def build(self):
```

Comment: Thank You ! This help a lot.